# Shortest not repeatable Substring with Suffix-Tree

Tags: string, algorithm, bioinformatics, suffix-tree

I need to design an efficient algorithm that finds the **Shortest non-repeatable Substring** in a text. In essence; the shortest string that appears only once in a text. This has to be made **only with suffix-tree**

Example 1:

`Text: AATGCCTA` then
`Result: G`

Example 2:

`Text: AAAAGGGG` then
`Result: AG`

Comment: The efficient way to construct a suffix tree is [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).

Comment: But how this construction alone solves my problem?

Comment: The shortes non-repeatable substring is the shortest unique prefix of all the suffixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortes non-repeatable substring is the shortest unique prefix of all the suffixes.

See [Minimum Unique Substrings and Maximum Repeats](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220444695_Minimum_Unique_Substrings_and_Maximum_Repeats) by Lucian Ilie
and W. F. Smyth.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful.